# .htaccess mod_reqrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I am trying to use mod rewrite in apache2 to make it going from this link:

```
 http://website.com/site/player.php?name=_Joosh
```

to using

```
http://website.com/site/u/_Joosh
```

Here is what I have tried so far in my .htaccess file I have.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^u/([A-Za-z0-9-+)/?$    player.php?name=$1    [NC,L]
```

And I have checked rewrite is an enabled mod in apache and I have added

```
Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
```

to my vhost file. Any help please?

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: http://joosh.me/mainpvp/.htaccess

Comment: Is **site** a folder?

Comment: Yes, there is the main site on the domain, then /site/ is a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule in your **/mainpvp/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^mainpvp/u/([A-Za-z0-9-+)/?$ /mainpvp/player.php?name=$1 [L]
```